# Add ImageView in textView like in another messaging app in objective c

Tags: objective-c

can anyone help me how i add selected photo in textField like in anotherMessaging App in ios.I use grooming text view for multiline text. I am not able to show selected photo  in textfield .Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]]];
```

Hope this works
or other manual way, creating view and place an image view  and then add textview at the top of it.